# JS / PUG Populate selector from nested array

Tags: pug

I have the following nested array of objects :

```
[entity{ name : "entity1",accounts [{name ="account1"}, {name ="account2"}]},
entity{ name : "entity2",accounts [{name ="account3"}, {name ="account4"}]}]]
```

With my template I have a selector for the `entity` and the `accounts` as below

```
label(for="entity_selector" class="form-label") Customer
 select#entity_selector(class="form-select mb-4 w-25" name = "customer_id")
       each entity in entities 
          option(value=entity._id) #{entity.name} 
label(for="account_selector" class="form-label") Account
select#account_selector(class="form-select mb-4 w-25" name = "account")
```

how I can populate and change the #account_selector options when the user change the entity selection ? I tried following script as but it doesn't trigger any event

```
script.
     var $entities = document.getElementById('entity_selector');
      $entities.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
         alert('some message')
      });
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using jQuery, hope it help someone,

first add jQuery script under `head tag`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

now add the following script in the `body`

```
script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var entities = !{JSON.stringify(entities)}; // get access to pug variables fron node
            //- $("#comment")[0].value = "TEST"
            entities[0].accounts.forEach((account) => {
                $("#account_selector").append($('<option>', { 
                    value: account._id,
                    text : account.name 
                }));
            })
        })
        $("#entity_selector").on('change', function() {
            $("#account_selector").empty() // empty the selector
            var entities = !{JSON.stringify(entities)}; 
            var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex 
            entities[selectedIndex].accounts.forEach((account) => {
                $("#account_selector").append($('<option>', { 
                    value: account._id,
                    text : account.name 
                }));
            })
        })
```

Please not the use of `!{JSON.stringify(entities)};` otherwise you will not be able to access pug variables inside of the jQuery script